# Error: anonymous function String & type of reference can't bind to const string type of initial value

Tags: c++

**Operation**

```
void CServiceList::GetAllState(string & retStateString)
{
    for_each
    (
        m_servicemap.begin(), m_servicemap.end(),
        [retStateString](const pair<string, CService*> & x)
        {
            CService* instance = x.second;
            instance->GetServerState(retStateString);//Error red line under retStateString
            //declaration of GetServerState. void CService::GetServerState(string & retStateString)
        }
    );
}
```

**Proposed Error:**
[image]

String & type of reference bind to const string type of initial value, the qualifer will be discarded

**Experiment:**

```
void test1()
{
    string aS = "bs";
    string & bS = aS;
    auto func = [bS]() { return bS; };
    cout << func(); //output: bs
    return ;
}
```

**Question:**

First code. string &  retStateString -> copy capture [ retStateString ] propose error

Experiment code. string & bS -> copy capture [bS] ok

why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you understand what you are doing or what is the issue.

In first, you capture the string by copy. Since the lambda's operator `()` is always marked `const` the captured string cannot be passes by reference. Only by const reference or pass a copy. Were you to capture the string by reference `[&retStateString]` the call would compile.

In second, you capture string by copy and then you return a copy of it. That's all there is.

Comment: I still confused. First code. string & retStateString -> copy capture [ retStateString ] propose error.
Experiment code. string & bS -> copy capture [bS] ok.
why

Comment: @doUWannaBuildASnowMan because the function you try to call wants an editable objects (non const). By default, lambdas do not allow any editing on captured-by-copy objects. You should pay more attention to const correctness.